# Change Network Location from Domain to Public

Tags: windows-server-2016, rras

In Our environment, We have a Windows Server running the Routing and Remote Access role, and functioning as a VPN server. Since this is the case, the server has two interfaces; One going to our internet gateway, to allow connections in from outside our network, and the other connecting to our internal network.

I would like to configure some firewall settings for the internet-facing interface. I would do this by configuring rules for the "public" profile, which should only effect public-network facing interfaces. This would work, aside from one issue; The server currently seems to think that both of the server's interfaces are connected to Domain Networks.

[image: as seen in Network and Sharing center. I've blocked out our Domain for security reasons.]

If I run the command `get-netconnectionprofile` in Powershell, I can see that both interfaces have the value `DomainAuthenticated` as their Network Category. Attempting to change this manually using the `set-netconnectionprofile` command returns a couple errors, most notably `the NetworkCategory cannot be changed from from 'domainauthenticated'`.

How can I resolve this? Any assistance is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change an adapters profile from Domain (DomainAuthenticated) to anything else.  This is not good when you are trying to mix networks together.  The way I worked around this was to block NLA using the firewall rules.

- Rule Type: Custom
- Program: Services -> Customize -> Network Location Awareness / NlaSvc
- Protocol and Ports: Any
- Local IP: Add the IP's that belong to the adapter(s) you want affected.
- Remote IP: Any IP
- Action: Block Connection
- Profile: Domain,Private,Public
- Name: Network Location Awareness - Deny IP Access

This prevents NLA from detecting and setting a profile to NIC's with the specified IP's.  Then you can use Powershell to force the NIC to what ever profile you want and set your firewall rules accordingly.  I recommend setting a script at machine startup to force the NIC to whatever profile you are wanting to ensure it doesn't change on you <- Experience talking there....

```
Get-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias $NIC | Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory Public
```

Sometimes Automatic...Is just backwards...